# Make a view of a linked table in Spring-Thymeleaf

Tags: sql, spring, thymeleaf

I have trouble to make a view of linked table in Thymeleaf.
In my database I have 3 tables: collaborators, languages, level and I have a linked table collab_laguages_level. In my repository class I have a query to show which languages for which collaborators.

[image]

In my controller I have my @RequestMapping:

[image]

But I have trouble to map it in my thymeleaf view. I've tried a lot of different things but nothing works. I want to create a particular profile for all the employees to show which languages (java, php, js...) they "speak".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a way to create a paginated view of your collaborators.

Please check this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-pagination) for creating **pagination with Thymeleaf and Spring**.

First you have to prepare the required pagination-information in your controller:

```
model.addAttribute("list", x.getContent()); // your list
int totalPages = list.getTotalPages();
    if (totalPages > 0) {
        List<Integer> pageNumbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, totalPages)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        model.addAttribute("pageNumbers", pageNumbers); // list of all page-numbers (so users can click on the specific page)
    }
```

Then in Thymeleaf you iterate over your list like this (simple example):

```
 <tr th:each="collaborator : ${list}">
            <td th:text="${collaborator.language}" />  // variable names of Collaborator entity
            <td th:text="${collaborator.languageLevel}" />
        </tr>
```

And below you make your pagination (simple example):

```
<div th:if="${list.totalPages > 0}" 
    th:each="pageNumber : ${pageNumbers}">
    <a th:href="@{/profiles(size=${list.size}, pages=${pageNumber})}"
        th:text=${pageNumber}></a>
</div>
```